# Why \allowbreak is not working?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, miktex

So, here's the code I have:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E =
\left\langle \mathbb{S},\allowbreak \mathbb{E},\allowbreak
f,\allowbreak \mathbb{V},\allowbreak \mathbb{R},\allowbreak
\mathbb{C},\allowbreak Op_a,\allowbreak Op_c,\allowbreak
Op_m \right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}
```

and here is the result (grey area denotes the edge of the page):

[image]

Obviously, `\allowbreak` does not do anything. Why is it?

Comment: Perhaps try '\mathlist' as shown here:  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode-breaks-citations

Comment: Just don't use `\left` and `\right`, which in this case do nothing. Then `\allowbreak` will work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/14996) I have two requests: Given the answer, could you edit the question title so that other people with a similar problem will find your question more easily? Could you also insert a few linebreaks in your code so that it will be easier for someone else to get an overview of your formula/text? :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is another case for which `\left` and `\right` are not appropriate:

1. there is no delimiter to increase the size of;
2. the spaces after commas cannot participate to stretching or shrinking together with the other spaces in the same line;
3. the formula is not breakable across lines under any circumstance.

So the first step to do is to remove `\left` and `\right` (and to disable any automatic feature in the editor). Then a carefully placed `\linebreak[0]` will help in the pagination.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\noindent\parbox{4cm}{
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \langle
  \mathbb{S},\mathbb{E},f,
  \mathbb{V},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\linebreak[0]
  Op_a,Op_c,Op_m \rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}

\noindent\parbox{6.5cm}{
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \langle
  \mathbb{S},\mathbb{E},f,\linebreak[0]
  \mathbb{V},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},
  Op_a,Op_c,Op_m \rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}

\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \langle
  \mathbb{S},\mathbb{E},\linebreak[0]
  f,\mathbb{V},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},
  Op_a,Op_c,Op_m \rangle$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that, by default, there's no stretching or shrinking of the spaces after commas (`\thinmuskip`) in math.

Comment: @HendrikVogt There could be. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following `middlebreak` macro:

[not using at all `\left` and `\right` was better in your posted case, as pointed out in comments; but then look at the second proposal below for more general usage]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% to be used within a \left \right pair
\def\middlebreak {\nulldelimiterspace0pt
\right.\allowbreak\mskip 0mu plus .5mu \nulldelimiterspace0pt\left.}%

\begin{document}

{%
\hsize 3cm
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \left\langle
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},\middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},\middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m \right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}%

{%
\hsize 7cm
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \left\langle
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},\middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},\middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m \right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}%

\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = \left\langle
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},\middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},\middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m \right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: middlebreak]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\newlength{\IrresponsibleFantasy}

\newcommand*{\ReserveVerticalSpace}[1]
   {\setlength{\IrresponsibleFantasy}{#1}\global\IrresponsibleFantasy=\IrresponsibleFantasy
    \parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{\IrresponsibleFantasy}}}

\newcommand*{\middlebreak}{\nulldelimiterspace0pt
\right.\allowbreak\mskip 0mu plus .5mu \nulldelimiterspace0pt
\left.\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{\IrresponsibleFantasy}}}%

\begin{document}

{%
\hsize 3cm
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = 
\left\langle\ReserveVerticalSpace{1cm}
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},
  \middlebreak {X^X}^X, \middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},
  \middlebreak {q_q}_q, \middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m 
\right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}%

{%
\hsize 7cm
\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = 
\left\langle\ReserveVerticalSpace{1cm}
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},
  \middlebreak {X^X}^X, \middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},
  \middlebreak {q_q}_q, \middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m 
\right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}
}%

\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E = 
\left\langle\ReserveVerticalSpace{1cm}
  \mathbb{S},\middlebreak \mathbb{E},
  \middlebreak {X^X}^X, \middlebreak f,\middlebreak
  \mathbb{V},\middlebreak \mathbb{R},\middlebreak \mathbb{C},
  \middlebreak {q_q}_q, \middlebreak
  Op_a,\middlebreak Op_c,\middlebreak Op_m 
\right\rangle$.
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

[image: middlebreakII]

Comment: You did test that right? try adding `\test` before `\right\rangle`, where `\test` is `\def\test{x^{(2)}}`. Now `\rangle` and `\langle` is scalled differently. Best solution is never to use `\left...\right` in text-mode math.

Comment: @daleif Well then add a phantom of the required height/depth. Removing the use of `\left` and `\right` was I admit the first thing to recommend to the OP in the case at hand; I didn't look at the actual enclosed contents. If items had varied more in height and depth I would have adjusted the method.

Comment: Another point is that in many cases `\left...\right` in the text create unnecessary large fences disrupting the line spacing. I general: don't encourage users to use it in the text

Comment: @jfbu your second proposal is truly neat. But bad bad you not to have added a strut among the first words of the text before the math group: look at your second example the one with `\hsize7cm`!

Comment: i haven't researched `\middlebreak`, but it appears that it causes the paragraph to be set ragged right, which wasn't requested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried after removing all math, and then repeating ten times the initial sentence. The paragraph appears ragged right when the width is `3cm` but not when it is `7cm`. It doesn't matter if the thing is within a theorem environment or not. So chances are the effect you observe is not related to the `\middlebreak` thing.

Comment: @jfbu -- apologies -- i've figured it out.  *all* lines are overfull at `3cm`, but unless you say `[draft]` with the document class, that fact will be obscured.  (i will *never* get used to this!  in my opinion, the wrong default has been chosen; it should be necessary to do something explicit to get rid of the "great black snock" that identifies overfull lines.  adding `[final]` for the last run isn't that onerous.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for this analysis -- I had noticed something was fishy with the paragraph at  `3cm`. Regarding the overfull rule, to be honest, I always appreciated that `LaTeX` had made it disappear in the default set-up... but I agree that being obliged to deal with them is probably the better way to learn how to correctly use `TeX` and `LaTeX`.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the token stream associated with your algebraic structure to automatically append `\allowbreak` after each comma and wrap its elements with an auto-sizing pair of angle brackets (excluding `\left...\right`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mstruct}{m}{%
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\ensuremath{\l_tmpa_tl}}
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {\box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box}
  \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {\box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box}
  \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {0.3em}
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim {1.2\l_tmpa_dim}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {,} {,\allowbreak}
  \ifmmode%
    \text{\fontsize{\l_tmpa_dim}{\l_tmpb_dim}\selectfont$\langle$}
  \else%
    {\fontsize{\l_tmpa_dim}{\l_tmpb_dim}\selectfont$\langle$}
  \fi
  \ensuremath{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \ifmmode%
    \text{\fontsize{\l_tmpa_dim}{\l_tmpb_dim}\selectfont$\rangle$}
  \else%
    {\fontsize{\l_tmpa_dim}{\l_tmpb_dim}\selectfont$\rangle$}
  \fi
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mstruct{\text{my}^{\text{very}^{\text{very}^{\text{very}^{\text{big}^\text{object}}}}}}

\mstruct{this,is,a,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,very,long,sentence,because,I'm,testing,mstruct,against,very,long,text,with,\text{my}^{\text{very}^{\text{very}^{\text{very}^{\text{big}^\text{object}}}}}}

\begin{theorem}
$\mstruct{\text{my}^{\text{very}^{\text{big}^\text{object}}}}_a^b$
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
...could be now considered as an algebraic structure $DB_E =
\mstruct{\mathbb{S}, \mathbb{E}, f, \mathbb{V}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, Op_a,
Op_c, Op_m}$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's `\vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl}` for. You're measuring the height of the *string* `\l_tmpa_tl`, not the height of the formula stored in the token listo. You could have a very big object in the argument, but this wouldn't lead to differently sized delimiters.

Comment: You're right, I think I got lucky because of a newline.  I was thinking that `\box_ht:N` returned the height of the rendered box, that needed to be initialized with the text of the token list because I could not initialize it with the token list directly.  I've updated my answer to use the `calc` package.

Comment: I found another way to do it without `calc`.  If you would, please review my latest solution.

Comment: It should be `\hbox_set:Nn` to begin with.

Comment: Why `hbox` instead of `vbox`?  The documentation for `\vbox_set:Nn` states, "Typesets the <contents> at natural height and then stores the result inside the <box>".  The documentation for `\hbox_set:Nn` states, "Typesets the <contents> at natural width and then stores the result inside the <box>".  Since I'm interested in the height of the rendered text it seems like I should use `\vbox_set:Nn`.

Comment: You are interested in the height of the material, which is surely recorded correctly with `\hbox_set:Nn`. I'll add my version, feel free to roll back.

Comment: I've updated it to use `\hbox_set:Nn`.  From briefly researching the differences between `hbox` and `vbox`, it seems `hbox` is indeed what is needed.  Thanks!